# How to manage partitions (not live/system) on a remote Linux server?

Tags: partitioning, ssh, gparted, remote, parted

To provide more context, let's say we have a remote Linux server with 2 disks and 3 partitions on it. For example, a system partition (`/dev/sda1`) and one more disk with 2 partitions on it (`/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2`). We would like to remotely shrink `/dev/sdb1` and resize/expand `/dev/sdb2` to fit the new free space on disk, after we shrink `/dev/sdb1`.

We could probably use some GUI tools, like [gparted](https://gparted.org/), over ssh with X11 forwarding and a local XServer running, but that requires us to install a lot of X-related packages on the remote server, which we probably don't want since server environments are usually headless (no GUI).

Another approach could be to use [parted](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/) (CLI tool) over ssh to do all the work, but this way appears to be most error-prone, since we need to know and take into account a lot of stuff about sectors' layout, size, etc. Is there any tool that wraps `parted` and makes it easy for us to use it?

Also, I was wondering can we maybe use [sshfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) for this scenario?

All the answers/suggestions will be appreciated, so feel free to chip in your 2 cents, please :)

Comment: Avoid getting fancy or complicated with remotes. That leads to expensive on-site service. Fire up a local test VM, learn how to use `parted`, practice the procedure and make all your mistakes in the test VM, and have complete backups of the remote before you start the operation for real.

Answer (score 1):

You're an experienced Windows Admin that also needs to manage this one Ubuntu machine remotely.  **:-)**

`parted` is indeed the way to go as `gparted` is the GUI wrapper for `parted` and `parted` is totally error-free if you:

- clone the remote machine in your lab as a VM
- `parted --list` first
- create a `bash` script from the commands you test in your VM
- execute the script remotely over `ssh`

And most important of all:

#### Ensure you have a reliable UPS and reliable on-site backups at the remote site!